# Dark camera view problem

Tags: camera

Hello I have a blender file with an animation that is the fruit of a long work. The problem is that now I need to use the camera view on it and when I click on the camera view it show me a total dark view with not even the usual camera rectangle borderlines.

Render image work correctly but I need only the camera view.

If I make a new blender file everything  work correctly I see well that what camera see. But I don't want to restart all my work for this problem. Maybe that I did tick a wrong option somewhere?

[image]

...

Edit: I tried to press the home button in camera view like Crantisz suggest but it only make the view back out of the camera view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in camera view and see the dark background, press <kbd>Home</kbd> button to reset the view, or use menu:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what is the home button. How could I have access to it? (my laptop has no numpad)

Comment: You can find it in menu: View → Frame all

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Oh! that's fun, this works different from menu. I'll check if I can solve this

Comment: All right, I've found it: View → Cameras → Frame Camera Bounds

Comment: I work ! Thank you so much.

Comment: Should be an issue caused by using Orbit around selection option. Not very useful, I don't suggest using it. You can always set center of viewport rotation by alt+MMB. But it's up to you